# The Tag ‘name’ property has been deprecated. Use ‘title’ instead

Tags: error-message, error

I keep seeing this deprecation message every time I upgrade Craft and cannot figure out what's going on for the life of me. There is nothing in the stack trace (that I can see) that points to a specific template file.

Below is the full stack trace:

```
> Deprecation error: The Tag ‘name’ property has been deprecated. Use ‘title’ instead.

>Called from /Users/Rhys/www/madebydusk.com/live/craft/app/models/TagModel.php (109)

>16 Craft\TagModel::getName() Called from /Users/Rhys/www/madebydusk.com/live/craft/app/framework/base/CComponent.php (111)

>15 Craft\TagModel::__get("name") Called from /Users/Rhys/www/madebydusk.com/live/craft/app/models/BaseModel.php (87)

>14 Craft\TagModel::__get("name") Called from /Users/Rhys/www/madebydusk.com/live/craft/app/models/BaseElementModel.php (141)

>13 Craft\TagModel::__get("name") Called from /Users/Rhys/www/madebydusk.com/live/craft/app/services/SearchService.php (78)

>12 Craft\SearchService::indexElementAttributes(Craft\TagModel) Called from /Users/Rhys/www/madebydusk.com/live/craft/app/tools/SearchIndexTool.php (99)

>11 Craft\SearchIndexTool::performAction(array("id" => "340", "type" => "Tag")) Called from /Users/Rhys/www/madebydusk.com/live/craft/app/controllers/ToolsController.php (50)

>10 Craft\ToolsController::actionPerformAction() Called from /Users/Rhys/www/madebydusk.com/live/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php (49)

>9  CInlineAction::runWithParams(array()) Called from /Users/Rhys/www/madebydusk.com/live/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php (308)

>8  Craft\ToolsController::runAction(CInlineAction) Called from /Users/Rhys/www/madebydusk.com/live/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php (286)

>7  Craft\ToolsController::runActionWithFilters(CInlineAction, array()) Called from /Users/Rhys/www/madebydusk.com/live/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php (265)

>6  Craft\ToolsController::run("performAction") Called from /Users/Rhys/www/madebydusk.com/live/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php (282)

>5  Craft\WebApp::runController("tools/performAction") Called from /Users/Rhys/www/madebydusk.com/live/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (817)

>4  Craft\WebApp::_processActionRequest() Called from /Users/Rhys/www/madebydusk.com/live/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (287)

>3  Craft\WebApp::processRequest() Called from /Users/Rhys/www/madebydusk.com/live/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php (185)

>2  Craft\WebApp::run() Called from /Users/Rhys/www/madebydusk.com/live/craft/app/index.php (62)

>1  require_once("/Users/Rhys/www/madebydusk.com/live/craft/app/index.php") Called from /Users/Rhys/www/madebydusk.com/live/public/index.php (19)
```

Comment: This is a bug that's been fixed for the next release of Craft.  Going to go ahead and vote to close!

Comment: Great! Another item ticked off my list, thanks Brad!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments by Brad, this is a bug and has been fixed in the next release.